# Electron memory tracing

Tags: electron, memory-profiling

I would like to check an Electron app memory usage by [`chrome://tracing`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/memory-infra/README.md).
I tried to apply [content tracing example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/content-tracing#contenttracing) from the documentation
with passing [`TraceCategoriesAndOptions`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all#tracecategoriesandoptions-object) and [`TraceConfig`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all#traceconfig-object) objects.

However, in both cases I got trace output without memory info.
Am I doing something wrong? Should I pass some additional args?

Trace output:

```
{"traceEvents":[
{"args":{"name":"swapper"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":3624,"tid":0,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"ThreadPoolForegroundWorker"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":3624,"tid":18088,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"ThreadPoolForegroundWorker"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":16656,"tid":18548,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"ThreadPoolForegroundWorker"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":18348,"tid":19212,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"ThreadPoolForegroundWorker"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":1864,"tid":18452,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"ThreadPoolForegroundWorker"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_name","ph":"M","pid":17516,"tid":18420,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"Service: network.mojom.NetworkService"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_name","ph":"M","pid":1864,"tid":0,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"Browser"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_name","ph":"M","pid":16656,"tid":0,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"Service: tracing.mojom.TracingService"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_name","ph":"M","pid":3624,"tid":0,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"GPU Process"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_name","ph":"M","pid":18348,"tid":0,"ts":0},
{"args":{"name":"Renderer"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_name","ph":"M","pid":17516,"tid":0,"ts":0},
{"args":{"number":12},"cat":"__metadata","name":"num_cpus","ph":"M","pid":3624,"tid":0,"ts":5701931484},
{"args":{"number":12},"cat":"__metadata","name":"num_cpus","ph":"M","pid":16656,"tid":0,"ts":5701931504},
{"args":{"number":12},"cat":"__metadata","name":"num_cpus","ph":"M","pid":18348,"tid":0,"ts":5701931510},
{"args":{"number":12},"cat":"__metadata","name":"num_cpus","ph":"M","pid":1864,"tid":0,"ts":5701931542},
{"args":{"number":12},"cat":"__metadata","name":"num_cpus","ph":"M","pid":17516,"tid":0,"ts":5701931566},
{"args":{"sort_index":-1},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_sort_index","ph":"M","pid":18348,"tid":19212,"ts":5701931572},
{"args":{"uptime":10},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_uptime_seconds","ph":"M","pid":18348,"tid":19212,"ts":5701931574},
{"args":{"sort_index":-6},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_sort_index","ph":"M","pid":16656,"tid":18548,"ts":5701931576},
{"args":{"uptime":10},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_uptime_seconds","ph":"M","pid":3624,"tid":18088,"ts":5701931578},
{"args":{"uptime":10},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_uptime_seconds","ph":"M","pid":16656,"tid":18548,"ts":5701931579},
{"args":{"uptime":10},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_uptime_seconds","ph":"M","pid":1864,"tid":18452,"ts":5701931613},
{"args":{"sort_index":-5},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_sort_index","ph":"M","pid":17516,"tid":16752,"ts":5701931621},
{"args":{"uptime":10},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_uptime_seconds","ph":"M","pid":17516,"tid":16752,"ts":5701931624},
{"args":{"labels":"Hello World!"},"cat":"__metadata","name":"process_labels","ph":"M","pid":17516,"tid":16752,"ts":5701931626},
{"args":{"sort_index":-1},"cat":"__metadata","name":"thread_sort_index","ph":"M","pid":17516,"tid":16752,"ts":5701931627}],"metadata":
{"chrome-bitness":64,"clock-domain":"WIN_QPC","command_line":"\"D:\\MemoryUsage\\POCs\\testApp2\\node_modules\\electron\\dist\\electron.exe\" --allow-file-access-from-files .","cpu-brand":"Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz","cpu-family":6,"cpu-model":158,"cpu-stepping":10,"gpu-devid":0,"gpu-driver":"","gpu-psver":"","gpu-venid":0,"gpu-vsver":"","highres-ticks":1,"network-type":"Unknown","num-cpus":12,"os-arch":"x86_64","os-name":"Windows NT","os-session":"local","os-version":"10.0.19041","os-wow64":"disabled","physical-memory":16303,"product-version":"Chrome/87.0.4280.67","trace-capture-datetime":"2020-12-1 11:22:49","trace-config":"{\"enable_argument_filter\":false,\"enable_systrace\":false,\"excluded_categories\":[\"*\"],\"record_mode\":\"record-until-full\"}","trace_processor_stats":{"android_log_num_failed":0,"android_log_num_skipped":0,"android_log_num_total":0,"clock_sync_cache_miss":14,"clock_sync_failure":0,"compact_sched_has_parse_errors":0,"compact_sched_switch_skipped":0,"compact_sched_waking_skipped":0,"counter_events_out_of_order":0,"empty_chrome_metadata":0,"flow_duplicate_id":0,"flow_end_without_start":0,"flow_invalid_id":0,"flow_no_enclosing_slice":0,"flow_step_without_start":0,"flow_without_direction":0,"ftrace_bundle_tokenizer_errors":0,"ftrace_packet_before_tracing_start":0,"fuchsia_invalid_event":0,"fuchsia_non_numeric_counters":0,"fuchsia_timestamp_overflow":0,"gpu_counters_invalid_spec":0,"gpu_counters_missing_spec":0,"gpu_render_stage_parser_errors":0,"graphics_frame_event_parser_errors":0,"guess_trace_type_duration_ns":1500,"heap_graph_location_parse_error":0,"heap_graph_non_finalized_graph":0,"heapprofd_missing_packet":0,"heapprofd_non_finalized_profile":0,"interned_data_tokenizer_errors":0,"invalid_clock_snapshots":0,"invalid_cpu_times":0,"json_tokenizer_failure":0,"meminfo_unknown_keys":0,"metatrace_overruns":0,"mismatched_sched_switch_tids":0,"misplaced_end_event":0,"mm_unknown_type":0,"ninja_parse_errors":0,"packages_list_has_parse_errors":0,"packages_list_has_read_errors":0,"parse_trace_duration_ns":275800,"perf_samples_skipped":0,"perf_samples_skipped_dataloss":0,"power_rail_unknown_index":0,"proc_stat_unknown_counters":0,"process_tracker_errors":0,"rss_stat_negative_size":0,"rss_stat_unknown_keys":0,"rss_stat_unknown_thread_for_mm_id":0,"sched_switch_out_of_order":0,"sched_waking_out_of_order":0,"slice_out_of_order":0,"stackprofile_invalid_callstack_id":0,"stackprofile_invalid_frame_id":0,"stackprofile_invalid_mapping_id":0,"stackprofile_invalid_string_id":0,"stackprofile_parser_error":0,"systrace_parse_failure":0,"task_state_invalid":0,"thread_time_in_state_out_of_order":0,"thread_time_in_state_unknown_cpu_freq":0,"tokenizer_skipped_packets":0,"traced_buf":[{"buffer_size":209715200,"bytes_overwritten":0,"bytes_read":688128,"bytes_written":688128,"chunks_committed_out_of_order":0,"chunks_discarded":0,"chunks_overwritten":0,"chunks_read":21,"chunks_rewritten":0,"chunks_written":21,"padding_bytes_cleared":0,"padding_bytes_written":0,"patches_failed":0,"patches_succeeded":0,"readaheads_failed":0,"readaheads_succeeded":0,"trace_writer_packet_loss":0,"write_wrap_count":0}],"traced_chunks_discarded":0,"traced_data_sources_registered":11,"traced_data_sources_seen":6,"traced_patches_discarded":0,"traced_producers_connected":5,"traced_producers_seen":0,"traced_total_buffers":1,"traced_tracing_sessions":1,"track_event_parser_errors":0,"track_event_tokenizer_errors":0,"vmstat_unknown_keys":0,"vulkan_allocations_invalid_string_id":0},"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) POC2/1.0.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Electron/11.0.3 Safari/537.36","v8-version":"8.7.220.25"}}
```

here is a source code that I tried:

```
const { app, contentTracing, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

const options1 = {
  traceOptions: "record-until-full",
  categoryFilter: "-*,disabled-by-default-memory-infra", //exclude all category, set memory-infra only
};

const options2 = {
  recording_mode: "record-until-full",
  enable_argument_filter: false,
  include_categories: ["disabled-by-default-memory-infra"],
  excluded_categories: ["*"],
  memory_dump_config: {
    triggers: [
      { mode: "light", periodic_interval_ms: 50 },
      { mode: "detailed", periodic_interval_ms: 1000 },
      { mode: "background", periodic_interval_ms: 1000 },
    ],
  },
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  (async () => {
    console.log("Tracing started");
    await contentTracing.startRecording(options2);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
    const path$$1 = await contentTracing.stopRecording();
    console.log("Tracing data recorded to " + path$$1);
  })();
});

const createWindow = () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );
};

try {
  app.on("ready", createWindow);
} catch (e) {
  console.err(e);
}
```

Comment: **Node** 12.18.3  
**Chrome** 87.0.4280.67  
**Electron** 11.0.3

Comment: About tracing: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool